# Survey form automatic slider randomization

Tags: javascript, slider, greasemonkey, autofill, tampermonkey

I'm trying to figure out a way to automatically randomize slider positions (type range) when I come across them on a webpage (mostly on web survey forms like Qualtrics or Surveymonkey). I would like to add this slider randomization to an already-existing autofill that I demonstrated below. But first, here are a couple examples of the type of sliders I would like to automate (with CSS/HTML):

[image]

&

[image]

Currently, I'm using the following script to randomly autofill survey forms on page load (radio buttons, text fields, etc). I would like to add slider randomization in the same vein to this script:

```
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
        // Save a random number
        var modifier = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000000);

        // Create a fake user data
        var user = {
            pass : modifier + "",
            mail : modifier + '@Example.com'
        };

        // Array to save data
        var save_data = [];

        // Check window for tags
        function check(win, tagName) {
            try {
                // Get tags
                tagName = win.document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
            } catch (e) {
                // Not found - Empty array
                tagName = []
            }

            // For each tag
            for (i = 0; i < tagName.length; i++) {

                // This tag
                var tag = tagName[i];

                // Exclude read-only or desabled
                if (tag.readOnly || tag.disabled) continue;

                // Get tag values
                var name = tag.name;
                var type = tag.type;
                var value = tag.value;

                // If Check box
                if ('checkbox' == type){
                    tag.checked = Math.random() > .5;
                }
                // If password
                else if ('password' == type){
                    value = user.pass;
                    // Update tag value
                    tag.value = value;
                }
                // If text
                else if ('text' == type) {
                    // If mail
                    if(name.match(/mail/i)){
                        value = user.mail;
                    }
                    // Update tag value
                    tag.value = value;
                }
                // If radio
                else if ('radio' == type) {
                    // If data don't exist
                    if (!save_data[name]) {
                        save_data[name] = 1;
                    }else{
                        save_data[name] ++;
                    }
                    // Check it with probabilities (depending on the length)
                    tag.checked = Math.random() < (1 / save_data[name]);
                }
                // If select
                else if (type.match(/^select/)){
                    // Set a random options
                    tag.selectedIndex = Math.random() * (tag.options.length - 1) + 1;
                }
            }
            // Try to set focus to the input
            if (tag) try {
                tag.focus()
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        function recursive(win) {
            check(win, 'password');
            check(win, 'select');
            check(win, 'input');

            // For each frame on page
            for (var i = 0; i < win.frames.length; i++) {
                // Check all frames inside
                recursive(win.frames[i])
            }
        }
        recursive(window);
    }());
```

Since I know that sliders are of the input type range, my added code would need to start with something that looks like this:

```
else if ('range' == type) {

                    if (!save_data[name]) {
                        save_data[name] = 1;
                    }else{
                        save_data[name] ++;
                    }

                    tag.checked = Math.random() < (1 / save_data[name]);
                }
```

As you can see, I am basing this code off the radio button portion of the script. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, and I am currently unable to find the syntax for how to select a new slider position or initiate the movement of a slider. I assume it works differently than a clickable check box or radio button. I know that sliders have ranges generally specified in the CSS/HTML, so this will obviously need to be accoutned for. Any and all help would be absolutely wonderful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[From w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_range_value.asp):

> Change the value of a slider control:
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("myRange").value = "75";
> ```

Tweaked it a bit to make it random (if your input range is between 0 and 100):

```
document.getElementById("myRange").value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The math part you posted I will likely supplement to randomize the input values. Unfortunately, the element ID will differ across the sites I will apply my code to. I need something that can manipulate the inherent input="range" characteristic of all of these sliders